# Seaborn Lineplot incorrectly attempts sort my already sorted data

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Whenever I try to lineplot my DataFrame, seaborn decide by default that it gets to decide that it isn't sorted, plotting my data from left to right instead of start to finish, the way it is indexed, leading to weird zig zags in otherwise smooth data.

Here is a screenshot of my DataFrame [image: DataFrame]

and here is the code to plot :

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
sns.lineplot(x ='cluster' , y = 'count', data= tmp, sort = False)
```

And here is the resulted plot screenshot : [image: Resuted zigzag plot]

My question is how to avoid that and have a smooth graph going from the top to the bottom

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just edited the question! Sorry for not being explicit

Comment: The few rows that you show of your data frame seem to correspond accurately with the path coordinates of the plotted line. What do you expect the graph to look like instead? Have you tried plotting `df[df.cluster.argsort()]`?

Comment: Your cluster names are integer, so it is sorted when plot. You can convert cluster names to string or plot against the index. But I'm not sure how to name 600+ clusters on the x-axis.

Comment: My DataFrame is already sorted that's why I set Sort = False, and even with it set to True, it gives the same results.

Comment: @QuangHoang I tried converting it to Strings, it didn't work, but for using the index, it works !

Answer (score 0):

Seaborn sorts values in the X-axis automatically if they are integers, so the solution was to use the index in the X-axis and keep setting the sort flag to its default value

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
sns.lineplot(x = tmp.index , y = 'cumsum', data= tmp)
```

Comment: I think this is a misconception. Seaborn does not sort anything, unless it is asked to so via `sort=True`.

Comment: What I meant is if you're plotting integers in the X-axis, they'll be shown sorted and not as they are in the data frame !

Comment: Oh, yes, because by default [`sort=True`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/09e7d61eaeed932c743976c877df2edd321a6c05/seaborn/relational.py#L1071).

Comment: Yeah, that is right ! and also when using the index you can face problems if you are trying to plot the cumulative sum and not the count. Let's say there is three entries with the same count [7,8,9], and in the DataFrame, they are not ordered in the index, this will cause anomalies in the cumsum line! So what I recommend is ordering by the index using sort_index( axis = 0) before calculating the cumsum