# How to combine Line PLots & legends in seaborn/matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe like this

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1],
                   'B': [200,300,400,800,1500,900,450,275,200],
                   'c': ['up','up','down','up','up','down','down','up','down'],
                   'd': ['r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r','r'],
                   })
```

When I do a line plot with seaborn with the code `sns.lineplot(data=df, x='A', y='B',ci=None)`. I get a plot like below.

[image]

As you can see, the points have not completely plotted. When I do the plot with the code below

```
upDF = df.loc[df['c']=='up']
downDF = df.loc[df['c']=='down']
sns.lineplot(data=upDF, x='A', y='B',ci=None, label = 'up');
sns.lineplot(data=downDF, x='A', y='B',ci=None, label = 'down');
plt.legend()
```

I get a plot like below

[image]

In this plot, all points are plotted, but they are 'disconnected'. How can I get a plot like below with the points connected & just only one legend (column 'D' or a constant can be used for legend)

[image]

If I use `sns.lineplot` on my actual data, I get the graph like below instead of `up` & `down` plotted separately.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure matplotlib. Select the rows after an up as part of the up Series to ensure joining the points. For the legend, add a label that starts with an underscore to be skipped:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = df['c']=='up'
upDF = df.loc[m|m.shift()]
downDF = df.loc[~m]
ax = plt.subplot()
upDF.plot(x='A', y='B', label='r', ax=ax)
downDF.plot(x='A', y='B', label='_skip', ax=ax)
ax.legend()
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the solution you have provided, The line still has 2 colors, how I get only one color?

Comment: Also, the `up` and '`down` values do not alternate. There can be a few consecutive '`up` values & a few `consecutive` down values. I will figure this out. Get one color "per line" is something I need help with.

Comment: I'm confused, if you want a single color, why do you split the data? Just do `df.plot(x='A', y='B', label='r')`

Comment: You are right. If I use `df.plot(x='A', y='B', label='r')`, I get the graph the way I want. How Do I achieve the same with `Seaborn`? Should I use something other than `lineplot`? I have updated my question to shown what I am getting with `sns.lineplot` with my real data (the df in this question is dummy data)

Comment: If you want to use `sns.lineplot` you need to disable aggregatio to prevent the points with same x to be aggregated, but I don't think you can make "parametric" curves, they will necessarily be sorted by increasing x

Comment: Actually I can get the graph I want with `sns.lineplot` ! I just have to pass `sort=False` in the arguments. I found this in this question (3rd comment in the answer). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883289/seaborn-lineplot-incorrectly-attempts-sort-my-already-sorted-data